# Lumen JWT send token with requests

Tags: laravel, api, authorization, jwt, lumen

Authentication is working, I have a few routes under `auth` middleware, Whenever i request it throws :

```
{
  "message": "Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header.",
  "status_code": 401
}
```

How can i send the token with the request like :

```
Authorization bearer {{Long token}}

It works with `postman`, How can i send the token with request header, Or in any other best way.
```

Route :

```
$api->get('/categories', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index',
    'as' => 'api.categories',
]);
```

Method :

```
public function index() {
    $lessons = \App\Category::all();
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken(); // $token have jwt token

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $lessons,
        'code' => 200,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the api? You has to be set in the header or in the query string by the caller. Try adding `?token={tokenvalue}` to your api link and test.

Comment: @sandeesh Yes i am using `postman`, I manually put the token in header.

Comment: What exactly is your question then? If it works in post man then you should do the same when calling it in other ways. How are you planning to call the api apart from postman? Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: @sandeesh user cannot give the token i address, There is a way where the api can get the token of the authenticated user automatically !

Comment: That's not how api's work. You need to send the token with each request. You are still not answering my question. How do you plan to consume the api apart from postman? Frontend through ajax? Mobile app? Third party api? Please be specific when asking questions. Typically a token is generated when a user performs a login or register and this token is sent back in the api response. The caller of the api needs to store this token locally depending on which platform it's being called from. Then use this locally stored token with each request.

Comment: Mobile app have to use it !!! So the mobile app have to store it locally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was pretty vague to answer. Please be more specific from next time. From your comments i could finally realise that you want to consume the api from a mobile app.

You need to return the token generated for an user either during login or during registration or any other authentication method/route you have. The mobile app needs to read this response and store the token locally. Then the app needs to inject this token in the request header for every single request. That's the normal api token workflow.

The app should also be coded to read the error response from requests and if it returns errors for expired or invalid token, the app needs to clear the locally stored token and then request the user to login again to generate a fresh token.

Answer (score 0):

you can use : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

requriment : 
    Laravel 4 or 5 (see compatibility table)
    PHP 5.4 +
 Steps: 
    1 : add below line in composer.json in require array
         "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
    2 : run "composer update" in your terminal
    3 : after this you have to register service provider 
        go to config/app.php
        and add 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' this in provider array
        and 'JWTAuth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth' , 'JWTFactory' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory' this to aliases array
    4 : publish pacakge : 
        "php artisan vendor:publis --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
    5 : generate secrate key in config file 
        'php artisan jwt:generate'
    6 : for addition configuration : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Configuration

```
Usage : 

AuthenticateController.php

use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}


You can also skip user authentication and just pass in a User object. e.g.
// grab some user
$user = User::first();

$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

The above two methods also have a second parameter where you can pass an array of custom claims. e.g.
$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];

JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims);
// or
JWTAuth::fromUser($user, $customClaims);

create token based on anything 
$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];

$payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);

$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
```

d